# Verb to speak about legal right

Tags: verbs, legalese

I have been thinking about it and I was wondering if there is single verb (or maybe a phrase) in English which can describe the attribution of legal rights to someone. Is there a specific verb used to express it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have to be more precise. To whom are you "attributing legal rights", to what end and for what reason? Is it a good thing or a bad thing? From whose perspective? What is the exact context? What is the register? What is your example sentence?

Comment: "attribution" is unclear.  Are you asking for a verb that means "to *assert* that someone has a legal right"?

Answer (score 2):

One common expression is ***to be  [entitled:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entitled)***

> - qualified for by right according to law; "we are all entitled to equal protection under the law"

The free Dictionary